# Insert BLOB test string bigger than 2000 or 4000 bytes

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, database-management, dbeaver

I have a table in oracle with a `BLOB` column, that can store XMLs and as well `XMLs` zipped. These are requirements from the customer and can't be changed. The tables will be created and I have to read and work with some information inside the `BLOBs`.

I have researched and any of the unclear solutions were clear or worked for me.

The problem I am facing is that to `INSERT` `XML` plain data bigger than `2000 bytes` with `utl_raw.cast_to_raw` using `DBeaver` as Database Manager. I received the message:

```
SQL Error [6502] [65000]: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_RAW", line 224
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: raw variable length too long
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_RAW", line 224
```

**Problems**

1. I have researched and `UTL_RAW` can't be longer than `2000 bytes`
2. it seems that there is another limitation of `4000 bytes` for `BLOBs` in Oracle

What could I do for those cases?

Comment: What do you want to do? Load zip file into blob column?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The problem I am facing is that to INSERT XML plain data bigger than 2000 bytes with utl_raw.cast_to_raw

Comment: What are you useing  for inserting data. SQPLUS or java app?

Comment: I use DBeaver, but I would bet that the problem would be as well with SQLPlus and others.

Comment: If i understand, you are trying to insert zip-ed xml document using regular SQL? Doing something like it `insert into table values(utl_file.UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('.....')`?

Comment: without utl_file-->  insert into table values(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('.....')

Comment: No, there's no limitation of 4000 bytes for BLOBs in Oracle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, you need to understand what LOBs are. They are "large data", possibly larger than any other data types in Oracle. They are like regular files on a filesystem. In order to write to a file on a filesytem, you'll have to

1. open the file for writing
2. truncate the file if you wish to start filling it from scratch
3. read your source data in chunks in a loop
4. append your data chunks to the file in the same loop, one by one
5. close the file

More or less the same is true for LOBs. In your table, a LOB (CLOB/BLOB/NCLOB) column is just a pointer/reference to another place on your disk storage holding the actual data. In standard Oracle terms, the pointer is called "LOB locator". You need to

1. open/initialize the LOB locator
2. truncate the LOB contents, if you wish to start filling it from scratch
3. append your data chunks to the LOB contents in a loop, one by one
4. close the LOB locator

In PL/SQL it could look like this:

```
-- create table blob_test(id number, b blob);

declare 
  v_b blob; 
  aaa raw(32767);
  longLine varchar2(32767);
begin 
  longLine :=  LPAD('aaaa', 32767,'x');
  aaa := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(longLine);
  insert into blob_test values(1,empty_blob()) returning b into v_b;
  dbms_lob.open(v_b,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);
  dbms_lob.writeappend(v_b,UTL_RAW.LENGTH (aaa) ,aaa);
  dbms_lob.close(LOB_LOC=>v_b);
  commit;
end;
```

An explanation:

1. initialize the LOB locator = `insert into blob_test values(1,empty_blob()) returning b into v_b;`
2. open the LOB locator for writing = `dbms_lob.open(v_b,dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);`
3. truncate the LOB contents, if you wish to start filling it from scratch ... This is done by the `empty_blob()` call in the `insert`.
4. append your data chunks to the LOB contents in a loop, one by one = here only one iteration of `dbms_lob.writeappend()`, appending only a single chunk `aaa` of length `utl_raw.length(aaa)` (maximum of 32767) into the LOB `v_b`
5. close the LOB locator = `dbms_lob.close(LOB_LOC=>v_b);`

Comment: I don't understand it and don't know how I am supposed to use it. Could you please explain how am I supposed to use that script in detail to include it in my own script that has multiple inserts, in case for example my table is called "MYTABLE" and I want to insert a string or XML of 5000 characters, how would it look like?

Comment: *)Info about oracle direcroty and BFILENAME [Info](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/bfilename.php)
*)Load file [Example](http://www.anujparashar.com/blog/loading-text-file-into-clob-field-in-oracle)
1) Copy your xml into oracle_server. 
2) Create oracle directory.
3) Grant privlege to the directory. 
4) Follow example.

Comment: The use case for LOB manipulations is too much dependent on the actual whereabouts of the manipulation itself. This answer nicely provides a general example, the rest should be on OP's self-studying abilities.

Answer (score -1):

Function `utl_raw.cast_to_raw` converts a value of data type VARCHAR2 into a raw value. Obviously, the length of the string is limited by VARCHAR2  datatype. If you need convert large text data to LOB you can use [DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1020355) procedure.

For example you can create function to convert large string value (clob as input) to blob. something like this -

```
create or replace function ClobToBlob (p_clob in clob) return blob is
   l_dest_offset   integer := 1;
   l_source_offset integer := 1;
   p_csid          number  := 0;
   l_lang_context  integer := DBMS_LOB.DEFAULT_LANG_CTX;
   l_warning       integer := DBMS_LOB.WARN_INCONVERTIBLE_CHAR;
   l_tmpblob blob;

  begin
   dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_tmpblob, true);
   DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB
  (
   l_tmpblob,
   p_clob,
   DBMS_LOB.LOBMAXSIZE,
   l_dest_offset,
   l_source_offset,
   p_csid,
   l_lang_context,
   l_warning
  );
  return l_tmpblob;
end;
```