# How to pass a parameter of CLOB type to Oracle stored procedure which is having 100k+ length string?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

```
 Create procedure p(p1 clob) as 
(
##code goes here..
);

exec p('100k+ length string...');
```

When I tried above procedure with 100k+ length string it is throwing ORA-20002: -20002:ORA-20002: -6502:ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error\nORA-06512: at

How can we pass the value to the stored procedure?
Do we need to increase the db_block_size to increase the capacity of CLOB datatype?

Comment: You're invoking your procedure passing a VARCHAR2 as an argument. You should declare a CLOB variable, fill it and pass that one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33166606/insert-blob-test-string-bigger-than-2000-or-4000-bytes/33171090#33171090

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the clob to the procedure just like other data types ([on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=abfef1a217cb3c1f2031eb8fb1b23e0f)):

```
create or replace procedure p (p1 clob) as 
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('clob len='||length (p1)); 
end;
/
declare 
    c clob := '123';
begin
    for i in 1..4 loop
        dbms_lob.append (c, rpad ('A', 32767, 'A')); end loop; 
    p (c);
end;
/
```

> clob len=131071

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken what a CLOB datatype can store with the procedure `put_line` of `dbms_output`

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( item IN VARCHAR2);
```

The item is a varchar2 object. So, if you want to print the output of a clob greater than the limit of a varchar, you need to create a different kind of code. In my case, I use always the below code to print a clob column:

```
create or replace procedure print_clob_to_output (p_clob in clob)
        is
          l_offset     pls_integer := 1;
          l_chars      pls_integer;
        begin
            loop
                exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
                l_chars := dbms_lob.instr(p_clob, chr(10), l_offset, 1);
                if l_chars is null or l_chars = 0 then
                    l_chars := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob) + 1;
                end if;
                dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
                l_offset := l_chars + 1;
            end loop;
        end print_clob_to_output;
```

Comment: It is not about printing or displaying the CLOB value. It is about passing the value of type CLOB having a bigger value to the stored procedure

Comment: you should have explained that. your code does not say that, because in your example you are using dbms_output.put_line, which makes an implicit conversion to varchar2 of the input parameter. So, you want to pass an input parameter to a procedure which could be a clob greater than 100K ?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass as input parameter to a procedure which is 100k+ length

Comment: then, what do you want to do with it ?? that is the main issue for giving you an answer